# Using Text With The Trianglify Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been using the Trianglify library and I've been loving it. My only problem is the way it handles text: it pushes it all to the top, whereas I want the randomly generated background to act as the background, with the text on it. Here's my code so far:

```
<script>
   var pattern = Trianglify({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    cell_size: 40});

  document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())

  </script>
```

and

```
        <div class="container-fluid" id="welcome">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1> Welcome to the website </h1>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Please help! Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question because I have the same issue.  Here's what I did.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="container1"></canvas>
<script>
var pattern = Trianglify({cell_size: 25, x_colors: 'Blues'});
pattern.canvas(document.getElementById('container1'));
</script>

<div class="screen-container trianglify-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>This is where my text goes</h3>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.trianglify-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20vh;
}
canvas#container1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**Explanation**
I am using Bootstrap, hence the `container` and `row` divs in the HTML.
Setting the `canvas#container1` to an `absolute` position fixes it and everything that follows in the HTML should come over it.  Setting `width` to 100vw and `height` to 100vh ensures it takes up the whole screen.

Setting the `trianglify-container` position to `relative` ensures it shows up relative to any `fixed` or `absolute` objects above it, in this case the canvas.  Using padding let's you move where you want the text.

If I wanted everything else on the page always to have the same trianglify background, I could do:

```
canvas#container1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```